# Modifying an existing c# file

Tags: c#, metaprogramming

I need to add some class/property level attributes to a number of c# files, so instead of manually adding them I thought to do it programmatically.

My question basically here is how to edit a c# file pro grammatically, I mean loading the c# file as codedom or AST and editing it and rewriting to the disk.

Any API's available in particular for this kind of work!

Comment: I have no idea why the tag `Metaprogramming` exist, but why did you decide it's related to your question?!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: we tend to downvote anyone who's not shown that they've put any effort into trying to solve the problem themselves. e.g. stackoverflow should never be the FIRST stop for a problem solution.

Comment: I think you need to be more descriptive and _prove_ what you have done/researched thus far.  'Class/property level attributes' isn't specific enough.  For example, using an `attribute` for a method vs. one for a `class` may have similar syntax, but the scope is _completely different_.

Comment: @Brian: My question is not about c#. I have rephrased the question.

Comment: @gdoron: Metaprogramming tag might make sense after my edit

Comment: C# file is a simple text file, you can open it with a notepad. edit it  as a such.

Comment: @Marc B: I tried to do this using T4, but found out that T4 is just text templating, so couldn't continue with it!

Comment: @gdoron: I'm aware of text manipulation, it's poor man's solution. Please don't teach me, if you don't know the answer, don't just downvote the questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [CodeDom](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y2k85ax6.aspx). You can load the existing classes, modify their object graph, and generate C# files (or even JIT compile and use).

Answer (score -1):

If they all have the same properties...

Make a class with all the properties; lets say you call it `FarmingObjectBase`
with the property:

```
FarmName{get;set;}
TractorCount{get;set;}
```

Make all your classes extend `FarmingObjectBase` so they get their properties, and they will all have these 2 properties,

Comment: Copy Past is probably your best bet if you don't have hundreds of classes and properties and want a fast and effective solution.... (just don't do it too quickly to avoid mistakes)